# Flask-Mail not working when deployed to Heroku

Tags: python, email, heroku, flask

I am attempting to deploy my python-flask backend to heroku while using flask-mail.
Everything works fine on local host. But my server keeps crashing on heroku.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)


app.config['TESTING'] = False
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'mail.gmx.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 587
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'some-email'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'some-password'
app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER'] = ('Some email', 'some-email')
app.config['MAIL_MAX_EMAILS'] = None
app.config['MAIL_ASCII_ATTACHMENTS'] = False

mail = Mail(app)



@app.route('/mail')
def send():
    msg = Message('Welcome!', recipients=['some-email'])
    msg.html = '<b>Welcome to Wx Safe Flight! Enjoy, and may good weather be with you!</b>'
    mail.send(msg)

    return 'Message has been sent!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True, port=5000)
```

Comment: This needs more info: What's in your `Procfile` and the trackback from the log files: `But my server keeps crashing` could mean many things.

Comment: Procfile: web: gunicorn app:app

Comment: The error I am receiving is a 503 crash error. With no more description.

Comment: sounds like you need to run the [`heroku logs` command](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-logs) if using the CLI, or view the logs for that dyno through the heroku web console, to establish the actual error behind that 503.

Comment: I have done that. And it is not pointing to an error besides "server crash". That is my issue. I wish I knew where the error was.

Comment: Did you find the reason why Flask Mail isn't working with Heroku? I'm on the same problem.